# Can XPath be used to Parse Static HTML/JSP pages

Tags: html, parsing, jsp, xpath

I'm in need of parsing the static JSP/HTML pages to identify the tags and labels in batch mode.

A program will run and read the view files in the given WAR or folder and parse it. Since it is not at run time DOM will not be available.

So need some directions on can it be done using XPath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XPath is designed to be used on XML documents only.

So, you've got to look for a parser which can parse JSP/HTML into a XML document. If you were using JSPX instead of JSP, then you'd just have used the Java SE's builtin JAXP for that.

```
InputStream input = getInputStreamOfJspOrHtml();
Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(input);
// ...
```

However, if you're using legacy JSP, probably full of *scriptlets*, and/or non-well-formed HTML (e.g. using `<br>` instead of `<br/>`), which would not validate as XML at all, then your best bet is using a lenient HTML parser which is forgiving with invalid syntax, such as [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/).

```
InputStream input = getInputStreamOfJspOrHtml();
Document document = new Tidy().parseDOM(input, null);
// ...
```

Either way, once you've got a `org.w3c.dom.Document` at your hands, then you can just run XPath on it the usual way.

Comment: Thanks BalusC.It's quite useful